# Document library - why sometimes "Send to 'Other location' " and sometimes "Sent to 'Copy' "

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, copy, send-to-destination

On one page of our SharePoint 2016 there is the button "Send to -> Other Location" at some libraries but at another library on the page "Send to -> Copy".

[image]".

What is the difference? Why is it so different?

Answer (score 1):

I searched online, however, there is no documentation about their differences. Via my test, I found they would be directed to a same page (Copy) when clicking them, so the function of them are same, just the names are different.

[image]

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no explanation at all in the internet. I have noticed that this even seems to depend on the user. A colleague of mine says "Send to copy" at the same file where I say "Send to location".